# Basic Python function issue

Tags: python, function

I'm writing my first app, following a simple Food Tracker app example in Real Python.
I would like to integrate it into a simple Python Practice App, asking for the actual day and storing it into a variable, removing that value from the weekdays list and start to work with the remain days.
For some reason when i run the code, only the second function is displayed, being the first completely ignored by the app.
Is there any chance someone could take a look at my piece of code and give me some hints on how to achieve this?

Code follows:

````
print('Python Practice Tracker App')
print('-' * 30)
print()

actual_day = []
weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat']
answers = []

print("Which day is today?")
print("1. Sun\t2. Mon\t3. Tue\t4. Wed\t5. Thur\t6. Fri\t7. Sat")
for a in actual_day:
   answer_day = input("Choose day by selecting the corresponding number:")
   if answer_day == 1:
       actual_day.append('Sun')
       weekdays.remove('Sun')
   elif answer_day == 2:
       actual_day.append('Mon')
       weekdays.remove('Mon')
   elif answer_day == 3:
       actual_day.append('Tue')
       weekdays.remove('Tue')
   elif answer_day == 4:
       actual_day.append('Wed')
       weekdays.remove('Wed')
   elif answer_day == 5:
       actual_day.append('Thur')
       weekdays.remove('Thur')
   elif answer_day == 6:
       actual_day.append('Fri')
       weekdays.remove('Fri')
   elif answer_day == 7:
       actual_day.append('Sat')
       weekdays.remove('Sat')
   else:
       print('Option not available. Choose a day with the corresponding number.')

   print(f"It's {a}. Should i practice python?")

for i in weekdays:
   print(f"Did you practiced {i}?")
   answer = input("'Y' or 'N'?")
   if answer == 'Y':
       answers.append(answer)

print()
print("Calculating the answer...")

if len(answers) == 6:
   print("You've been practicing hard, you could have some spare time.")
elif len(answers) == 5:
   print("You're on schedule, do as you see fit.")
else:
   print('You need to practice.') ```
````

Comment: Your loop: `for a in actual_day:` does nothing because: `actual_day = []` means `actual_day` is an empty list.

Comment: When you try to iterate over `actual_day`, it is an empty list, and so the loop never executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two issues I could spot in your code.

First one is that your `actual_day` variable is an empty list, so your for loop is not going to execute.

Secondly, even though python is a dynamically-typed language, that does not mean number could be compared to string directly.
In your case,

```
answer_day = input("Choose day by selecting the corresponding number:")
```

will give you an `str`. In the following `if-elif` block, you are comparing `answer_day` with numbers like `1,2,3,4`. They will never equal to each other because they are in different types.

Two solution:
1. Convert the `answer_day` to int by `answer_day = int(answer_day)`.
2. Add quotes around each number in `if-elif` block, so they become `if answer_day == '1':`

Good luck!

Comment: I've managed to get it working by working only with strings and instead of a list assign the value to a string as well...

It works now, thanks for the time spent and for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

When execution reaches `for a in actual_day:`, `actual_day` is empty and no iteration occurs.

Consider a do-while or a primed while loop. That is, take input (and cast it to an int like @ivysaur-yw recommended), and then loop through it like so:

```
a = int(input())
while a > 0 and a < 8:
  do something
  a = int(input())
```

Comment: I've come with a simple solution to get it work based on the empty list which was preventing the code from running properly.
I guess i'll try a second version using a do-while.
Thanks